# How do I shorten the title lenghs with Elementor theme?

Tags: title, limit, characters

Hi guys I've searched this for too long and I am getting tired now. I need to set a limit on my post titles but I don't know how to do it. On google there are snippets of 300000000 codes to do the same thing but I don't understand where to put these and HOW. I am a total newbie. I am building my website with Elementor and I need the title to trim at an exact character limit. How do I do it? Please help me!!

Comment: 3rd party plugin dev support is off topic here, if a standard WP answer does not work for you, or this isn't a standard post title, then you'll need to ask Elementor support or go to an Elementor community to ask. If you already have a snippet though you should share that and ask where it goes

Answer (score 1):

Exactly "where" may differ depending on your theme setup. However, there are some global-ish ways to do this if you want to tackle it that way.

```php
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_trim_words' );

function my_trim_words( $title )
{
    // limit to ten words
    return wp_trim_words( $title, 10, '' );
}
```

If you'd like to do this for a particular post type, you can do it like this:

```php
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_trim_words_by_post_type', 10, 2 );

function my_trim_words_by_post_type( $title, $post_id )
{
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );

    if( 'product' == $post_type ) { 
        return $title;

    // limit to ten words
    return wp_trim_words( $title, 10, '' );
}
```

If it's within the theme templates (frontend files) that you're wanting to do this in very specific areas, you can use it this way in your templates:

```php
<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 5 ); ?>
```